# How to Insert multiple values on multiple column with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multiple-select

I'm kinda new to Laravel,
I ran into some problems with inserting multiple select to multiple columns in the database.

Here my view I'm using select picker for multiple select

```
  <select multiple="multiple"  name=language[] id="language[]" class="selectpicker"  data-selected-text-format="count">
    <option name="En">English</option>
    <option  name="It">Italian</option>
    <option  name="Ar">Arabic</option>                            
    <option  name="Jp">Japanese</option>
    </select>
```

The languages table:

```
+----+---------+---------+--------+--------+
| id | English | Italian | Arabic |Japanese|
+----+---------+---------+--------+--------+
|  1 |         |         |        |        |
|  2 |         |         |        |        |
|  3 |         |         |        |        |
+----+---------+---------+--------+--------+
```

How can I insert data to each column in the controller?
Here what I'm trying to do!

```
+----+---------+---------+--------+--------+
| id | English | Italian | Arabic |Japanese|
+----+---------+---------+--------+--------+
|  1 |   En    |         |   Ar   |   Jp   |
|  2 |         |    It   |        |        |
|  3 |   En    |         |        |   Jp   |
+----+---------+---------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the tables `id` column is set to `auto increment`. and other columns as `nullable`.

```php
$languages = request('languages');

DB::table('table_name')->insert([
    'English' => in_array('En', $languages) ? 'En' : null,
    'Italian' => in_array('It', $languages) ? 'It' : null,
    'Arabic' => in_array('Ar', $languages) ? 'Ar' : null,
    'Japanese' => in_array('Jp', $languages) ? 'Jp' : null,
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll receive an array `language` in your controller so you can check if the language exists add it to the DB :

```
$en = $it = $ar = $jp = null;

if(in_array('En', $language))
    $en = 'En';
if(in_array('It', $language))
    $it = 'It';
if(in_array('Ar', $language))
    $ar = 'Ar';
if(in_array('Jp', $language))
    $jp = 'Jp';

ModelName::insert(['English' => $en, 'Italian' => $it, 'Arabic' => $ar, 'Japanes' => $jp]);
```

Comment: thank you for answering i try it and that gave me null inserting for all of them.

Comment: You must debug your code and give me the right specific issue. or you can share with us the content of your controller or just the relevant action code.